# Sublime text 2 - highlight modified sidebar labels

Tags: sublimetext2, highlight, sidebar

I´m trying to modify Sublime to highlight modified sidebar labels.

I used this piece of code and it`s variations, like "sidebar_tree", sidebar_tree_row etc., but it doesn´t work.

```
    {
        "class"   : "sidebar_label",
        "settings": ["highlight_modified_sidebar_label_row"],
        "parents" : [{"class": "sidebar_label_control", "attributes":  ["dirty"]}],
        "fg"      : [245, 100, 90]
    }
```

Using Soda Dark theme, and already have enabled highlight modified tabs, but since I have opened 20 scripts, tabs are all pressed together.
So I figured to highlight sidebar labels, but code won´t cooperate.